# Axios POST request is shown as GET in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am making a POST request with Axios from my React JS app. My question is that I even though I am making a POST request, I am seeing a GET request being made in the Chrome console.

Here's my code making the request.

```js
const data = {
  // password1: payload.password1,
  // password2: payload.password2,
  password: payload.password1,
  email: payload.email,
  // firstname: payload.firstname,
  // lastname: payload.lastname
  profile: {
    referral: payload.refId
  }
};
console.log(data);
const url = `${API_URL}/api/users/create`;

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data,
  url
};

return Axios(options).then(
    res => {
      console.log(res.data.token);
      dispatch(receiveSignUp(res.data.token));
      dispatch(saveOnLocalStorage(res.data.token, "authToken"));
    },
    err => {
      console.log("ERR", err);
      // dispatch(errorSignUp(err.response.data));
    }
```

Here is what I see in the console.

[image]

Comment: This is called pre flight request. it should handled by server,

Comment: HTTP 405 status code is defined as Method Not Allowed, and this status code is a situation where "the method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI."

Comment: Did you try this url with postman?